# Pairwise Earth Mover Distance across all documents (word2vec representations)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, distance, word2vec

Is there a library that will take a list of documents and en masse compute the nxn matrix of distances - where the word2vec model is supplied? I can see that genism allows you to do this between two documents - but I need a fast comparison across all docs. like sklearns cosine_similarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Word Mover's Distance" (earth-mover's distance applied to groups of word-vectors) is a fairly involved optimization calculation dependent on every word in each document.

I'm not aware of any tricks that would help it go faster when calculating many at once – even many distances to the same document.

So the only thing needed to calculate pairwise distances are nested loops to consider each (order-ignoring unique) pairing.

For example, assuming your list of documents (each a list-of-words) is `docs`, a gensim word-vector model in `model`, and `numpy` imported as `np`, you could calculate the array of pairwise distances D with:

```
D = np.zeros((len(docs), len(docs)))
for i in range(len(docs)):
    for j in range(len(docs)):
        if i == j:
            continue  # self-distance is 0.0
        if i > j:
            D[i, j] = D[j, i]  # re-use earlier calc
        D[i, j] = model.wmdistance(docs[i], docs[j])
```

It may take a while, but you'll then have all pairwise distances in array D.

Comment: nested loops are slower in python - may switch to Java. Thanks for the ehads up though.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the accepted answer you may want to use the faster wmd library [wmd-relax](https://github.com/src-d/wmd-relax/).

The example then could be adjusted to:

```
D[i, j] = docs[i].similarity(docs[j])
```